# sed find and replace from line number

Tags: sed, command-substitution

I need to copy line 3 and later from file a to file b (starting from line 3)

File a.py

```
import a

print('file a')
```

Original File b.py

```
import b

print('file b')
```

After copy

```
import b

print('file a')
```

I tried to use `sed -n 3r<(sed -n '3,$p' a.py) b.py`, but it inserts the lines instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "3c $(sed -n '3p' a.py)" b.py
import b

print('file a')
```

Use command substitution to allow another `sed` command to be run as an arguments and `c` to replace the contents of line  3.

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you expalin a little bit of the `c` and dollar sign here?

Comment: @user2236600 Please check edit

Comment: It seems it only copies line 3. How about if I want to copy from line 3 and after?

Comment: @user2236600 Do you mean something like this? `sed -e "3{e sed -n '3,\$p' a.py" -e "d}" b.py`

Comment: Thanks, I modeified a little bit `sed -i -e "3{e sed -n '3,\$p' a.py" -e "d}" b.py` and that works perfectly. Would you mind expalining a little bit about the expression?

Comment: @user2236600 The `sed` command `e`xecutes an inline `sed` command on line 3 to print everything from line 3 to the last line from its command to the third line of the file to be changed.  If this or any other answer answers your question, please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: I see. What does this part `-e "d}"` mean and why it's separated from the previous expression?

Comment: @user2236600 `-e` is an expression and will allow us to chain multiple parts such as a closing curly brace `}` that cannot be closed following the use of `a`,`i`,`c`,`e` etc. The `d` deletes the data you do not want. Try it and see the results. Also a great way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -n 3p filea | sed -i -e '3r /dev/stdin' -e '3d' fileb
```

Output line 3 of `filea` to `/dev/stdout`.

Pipe that output to a second sed invocation that reads that line in on line 3 and then deletes the original line.

N.B. The `-i` amends `fileb` in situ.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
sed -i '' '3,$d' b.py ; sed '1,2d' a.py >> b.py
```

This translates as "amputate lines 3 and below from `b.py`, then echo lines 3 and below from `a.py` and append them to `b.py`".